# Looking to get External and Internal DNS to work with IIS and Url Rewrite for multiple sites

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

Good morning, I am looking for advice on properly setting up IIS to work with Sophos UTM.  Currently, I have IIS set up on a server, with two sites, both bound to https.  Site A is bound to port 443, and Site B is bound to port 444.  Each site has their own certificate used in the bindings, plus both sites are using the same IP address.  Internal DNS servers correctly resolve each site to the same IP address.
Site A uses a OpenID Connection call to Site B on login so it will send multiple queries, first for authorization, then if not, for login.  In the app settings for both sites, I have the setting to show siteb:444, so that the various applications can call it correctly.  Internally this works fine.  I began to have issues with the setup for the Sophos UTM.  The external DNS records for Site A and Site B point to the External interface of the Sophos UTM.  I have virtual and real servers set up in Sophos UTM for each of the sites.  The Virtual Server for Site A uses the same certificate that is on IIS and is set for HTTPS and Redirect for port 443, but is bound to Real Server Port 443.  The Virtual Server for Site B uses the same certificate that is on IIS and is set for HTTP and Redirect for Port 443, but is bound to Real Server Port 444.  Each Real Server points to the same IP address as the IIS server, just different ports.
If I enter the website for Site B and head to a specific page (i.e. /.well-known/openid-configuration), I get a response from Site B and the page that I am looking for is displayed.  If I enter the website for Site A and head to any of the open pages, that are not behind authentication, they display correctly. My issue then comes when I try to login from Site A.  When it passes over to Site B, Site B passes back out to the external DNS what is Site B:444?  This causes time outs, since the external DNS does not understand the port it says this site cannot be found.
On the advice of Microsoft, I installed URL Rewrite and ARR and created a Reverse Proxy for Site B.  I have Failed tracing enabled for the site so that I can see what is happening.  The rule is as follows, I modified the Inbound Rules matching pattern but did not really change the outbound pattern:

```
<rewrite>
   <outboundRules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://siteb.domain.com:444/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://siteb.domain.com/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
    <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(https?)://(.*)(.domain.com)/(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}://siteb.domain.com:444/{R:4}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
</rules>
```

Now with the URL Rewrite rules enabled, I am unable to get this to work internally, or externally.  When Site A makes the call to Site B:444 it gives a 500.52 error or a 404 error.  When I asked Microsoft what was wrong they said that nothing was wrong with the URL Rewrite, but that my UTM was preventing the traffic from reaching things correctly, then I mentioned that I was having the problem internally since adding the rewrite rules.  This met with I am putting the website into the browser wrong.  This I seriously doubt since I had it working internally prior to using the URL Rewrite rules.
I have searched around quite a bit for the correct way to do the URL Rewrite, and most of what I have found does not match my situation.  I am not rewriting from port 80 to port 443.  I am not adding /default.aspx onto the end of the string.
What I am simply trying to do is remove the port from application settings on each site so it shows as siteb rather than siteb:444, and at the same time when traffic hits Site B it knows to rewrite the inbound as SiteB:444/(.*) and outbound it as SiteB/(.*) so that the UTM can make this work correctly both internally and externally.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can be able to do this correctly?

Comment: If you are using IIS 8 and above, never use non-standard ports for HTTPS like 444. All HTTPS bindings can be on port 443 with SNI configured (even if this server has a single external IP address).

Comment: Thank you that was the answer.  I had tried both on port 443 previously, but never had the Server Name Indication checked.  When I set both to 443, ensured the correct certificates, and checked SNI, I was able to start both.  Works internally now, and it somewhat working externally.  I just have to get the right configuration for the UTM

Comment: Unfortunately on a public general forum like Stack Exchange, vendor products are not often discussed if they are only used by a small community of users. You should try the vendor support channels or their own forums, like https://community.sophos.com/utm-firewall/f

Comment: I already had a query open there, it was more or less, it seems to work externally, but until I fix that issue, I am not 100 precent sure it is fixed.